# Semantic segmentation performance: Multi-class vs Two-class

Tags: tensorflow, semantic-segmentation, deeplab

We are developing an application for semantic segmentation for PC and Mobile Platform.Initially we tried the current state-of-the art DeeplabV3+ framework from google.The data-set used was Pascal VOC and the model from the official model zoo performed very well in terms of accuracy (tensorflow).The performance of the model in PC and mobile (converted to coreml & tflite) were not satisfactory as per our requirements.Even though we tried different model optimization and quantization techniques, we could not achieve a good balance between performance and accuracy.

However, we are actually concerned only with segmentation of a single class (within PASCAL VOC).But the model computes the segmentation mask for each of the class-labels, which seems to be redundant in our case.So, if we train the network with just a single class(background extra), will it improve the performance in terms of speed?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, it'll improve speed in terms that, it won't have to spend extra time segmenting other classes, if it is not the class you want, it's gonna move ahead.